# Can't install CR alongside CRD in single Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install CRDs as part of an Helm chart, and deploy CR in the same chart.

The CRD is put on a *crds* folder, as per the [Helm official documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/custom_resource_definitions/#method-1-let-helm-do-it-for-you).

This is the CRD that is installed: [sigstore/policy-controller/templates/crds/clusterimagepolicy.yaml](https://github.com/sigstore/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/policy-controller/templates/crds/clusterimagepolicy.yaml)

The CR is put in a *policies* folder alongside other templates. Here is an example of custom resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: policy.sigstore.dev/v1beta1
kind: ClusterImagePolicy
metadata:
  name: some-policy
spec:
    images:
    - glob: "**"
    authorities:
    - key:
        secretRef:
          name: key
```

When I try to deploy the chart, I have the following error:
`unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "some-policy" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterImagePolicy" in version "policy.sigstore.dev/v1beta1" │ ensure CRDs are installed first`

Answer (score 0):

Run `helm show crds [CHART] [flags]` to make sure if helm can find your crds.
This happened to me when I put the /crds folder in the wrong directory (should be in the top helm folder but not within /templates)